# GNU screen mimic emacs frameset-to-register by writing layout to file

Tags: gnu-screen

One useful feature of Emacs is the ability to save the layout of the current frame to a register `C-x r f <letter>` and restore it later `C-x r j <letter>`.

In screen it can be a little tedious trying to reconstruct a layout after closing all but one buffer with `C-a Q` or something similar. From what I can gather screen does not have anything resembling emacs registers. I'm trying to figure out a way to simulate the emacs feature. Does screen have the ability to dump its current layout state to a file that can be read from later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the only files which screen writes are enumerated in [`screen.h`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/screen.h#n185):

```
#define DUMP_TERMCAP    0 /* WriteFile() options */
#define DUMP_HARDCOPY   1
#define DUMP_EXCHANGE   2
#define DUMP_SCROLLBACK 3
```

and those are documented in the manual page (none are the *layout* as such).

Comment: As a follow-up question, is it even possible to inspect the layout of a running screen process? If there's some way to call `screen <arguments>` and get the layout, I am just as happy redirecting that to a file and then writing a script to reconstitute the original screen layout.

Comment: It's just in memory - I don't know how much work would be needed to make a dump of the layout.